# Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option in facebook_base.php

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

A week ago I started to notice a problem with the php sdk file -  facebook_base.php

sometimes when connected facebook member visit the site and the auto-login trigger I get 2 errors and sometimes only the first error (that is why I used it in my problem title)+ the site shows up but without showing that user is connected.

after a refresh no error is shown and the site for connected member shows up.

I've tried new version of php API and also old ones that worked and still problem remained.

any ideas what can cause the problem?

UPDATE: similar problem spotted here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/207087046099691?browse=search_512a0e37e7ecf6136191651

this is the errors:

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option in /home/admin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/includes/base_facebook.php on line 970

Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values in /home/admin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/includes/base_facebook.php on line 946
```

Comment: You have to debug and find out what constant is being marked as invalid.

Comment: The only actions from my code are this -

require_once('includes/facebook.php');

define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'XXXXX');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'XXX');
$fb_api_lang='en_US';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXX',
  'cookie' => true
));
    $user  = $facebook->getUser(); 

And the errors shows without any normal behavior sometimes its there and sometimes it works perfect.

Comment: also spotted similar problem here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/207087046099691?browse=search_512a0e37e7ecf6136191651

Comment: Then you should talk with facebook dev support